# How can I find all objects of a model type that share a many-to-many-relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset

So, I have two model classes, let's use the django docs example and call them Person and Group. These are related in a many-to-many relationship - a Person can be in multiple Groups, and Groups can have multiple Persons. If I have a single Person object, what's the best way to find all other Persons with whom they share a group?

edit: This is sort of a loose layout of my code:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    {various other fields}
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which of the two models contain the ManyToMany Field. It it is in your "Group" model this should work ("person" being your reference person):

```
qs = Person.objects.filter(group__in=person.group_set.all()).exclude(id=person.pk).distinct()
```

giving you all Person objects sharing a group without doubles. If the m2m field is in your Person model this should do the job

```
qs = Person.objects.filter(groups__in=person.groups.all()).exclude(id=person.pk).distinct()
```

Comment: So based on my code that I've added, you're saying the latter example should work for me?

Comment: Sorry, the second code contained an error. Fixed it and tested it with you model. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    details = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    status_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    active = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    persons = models.ForeignKey(
        'Person',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='group_set'
    )

...

in_group_count = (
    Person.objects
    .filter(status_id__in=[2, 1], active=1)
    .annotate(order_num=Count('group_set'))
    .filter(order_num__gt=0).count()
)
not_in_group_count = (
    Person.objects
    .filter(status_id__in=[2, 1], active=1)
    .annotate(order_num=Count('group_set'))
    .filter(order_num__lte=0).count()
)
in_group_value = (
    Person.objects
    .filter(status_id__in=[2, 1], active=1)
    .annotate(order_num=Count('group_set'))
    .filter(order_num__gt=0).values()
)
```

Comment: Please elaborate. How does this code provide an answer?

Comment: in the list **in_group_value** we will have all members of the group

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear that I'm explicitly using a ManyToManyField, and just just a foreign key relationship.